# ReferenceError: $ is not defined - it used to work fine but now it broke - Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm getting a reference error of $ undefined for a function in a script tag in an html document. However, the code inside of it does still execute, it just simply doesn't show it within a modal for stripe checkout as it should (it goes to it's own page).

I have looked at posts on other answers and my assets do seem to be loaded correctly. I did not change the order of the js below from the time it worked until now. The only thing I changed was the location of some  tags for the partials that were rendered in this page. Unfortunately I had not committed my changes all day so I can't simply rollback the changes.

Here is the setup I have:

stack.js (my layout's js file):

```
//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require stack/vendors/vendors.min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/raphael-min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/chart.min
//= require stack/vendors/charts/jquery.sparkline.min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/unslider-min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/wNumb
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/nouislider.min
//= require stack/vendors/extensions/jquery.steps.min
//= require stack/vendors/timeline/horizontal-timeline
//= require stack/core/app-menu
//= require stack/core/app
//= require stack/scripts/pages/dashboard-ecommerce
//= require_tree ./common
```

my in page script:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: "<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>",
          image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
          locale: 'auto', 
          currency: "<%= @plan.currency %>",
          token: function(token) {
            var my_form = $('#stripe-form');
            console.log(my_form);
            var url = my_form.attr('action');
            console.log(url);
            var form_data = my_form.serialize();
            console.log(form_data);

            var submission = $.post(url, form_data + "&stripeToken="+ token.id);
            //$.post(url, token + submission);
            submission.success(function(result) {
              document.getElementById('subscribed').value = 1;
              $("#steps-uid-0-t-2").click();
              console.log("success" + result);   
            });
            submission.error(function() {
                alert("ajax error");
            });
            //You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
            //Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
          }
        });

        document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          // Open Checkout with further options:
          handler.open({   
            email: "<%=current_user.email%>",
            zipCode: true,
            amount: <%= @plan.price_cents %>
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
          handler.close();
        });
});
</script>
```

Partial were that script exists:

```
    <h6><i class="step-icon fa fa-credit-card"></i></h6>
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <button id="customButton">Subscribe</button>
        <%= form_tag('/subscription_checkout', {method: :post, id:"stripe-form"}) do %>
          <input name="subscribed" id="subscribed" type="hidden" value= false></input>
          <input name="id" type="hidden" value= "<%= @plan.pg_plan_id %>"></input>
          <input name="property_id" type="hidden" id="property_id" value= ""></input>
        <% end %>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This page is a partial that is nested inside another partial. There is another view that partial just before this one that uses the google places API, however both were working fine before until something changed (not sure what) and I stated getting the $ undefined error on that function. All the code within that function still executes just fine.

Javascript file for this controller:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var property_id;
  if (page.controller() == 'properties')
  { if ($(".icons-tab-steps" != 'undefined') )
    {

      // Wizard tabs with icons setup
      $(".icons-tab-steps").steps({
        headerTag: "h6",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        useURLhash: true,
        showStepURLhash: true,
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#title#</span>Step#index#',
        labels: {
            finish: 'Submit'
        },
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
        {
          // Always allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
          if (currentIndex > newIndex)
          {

            return true;

          }

          if (currentIndex < newIndex)
          {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(currentIndex);  
            console.log('property_id' + property_id);

              var form_id = "#form-step" + currentIndex; 
              console.log('Form ID:' + form_id);
              var my_form = $(form_id);
              console.log(my_form);
              var url = $(form_id).attr('action');
              console.log(url);
              var form_data = my_form.serialize();

              var submission = $.post(url, form_data);
              if (currentIndex == 0)   ///property form
              {   
                submission.success(function(result) {
                  console.log(result);
                  property_id = result.property_id;
                  alert("ajax success property_id:" + result.property_id);
                  //$('#shopResultsContainer').html(result.ViewMarkup);
                  console.log('Property ID after post: ' + property_id);
                  document.getElementById('property_id').value = property_id;
                  console.log('Property ID field' + document.getElementById('property_id').value);
                  return true
                });
                submission.error(function() {
                    alert("ajax error");
                    return true
                });
              }
              if (currentIndex == 1)   ///Stripe Payment form
              {
                if (document.getElementById('subscribed').value == 1)
                {
                  return true
                }
                else {
                  var skip = confirm("You have not subscribed to a data plan yet. Do you wish to continue?");
                  return skip;
                }
              }

          }
          return true
          },
          onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
          {
              return true
          },
          onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
          {
              alert("Submitted!");
          }
      });
      //if statement for existence of tag
    }


  ////END IF STATEMENT BELOW 
  }


});
```

Any pointers on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the `jquery-rails` gem to your gemfile?

Comment: This is going to be very hard for someone to answer for you. You appear to have a kitchen-sink approach and don't appear to be using source control management. I.e. you've eschewed the last several decades worth of best practices and recommendations for developing software in a way that helps debug these sorts of problems. You'll need to create a more pared-down reproduction of your issue with as little code as possible before we can really help.

Comment: @hashrocket yes jquery-rails is in the gem.file

Comment: When you view the source of the page, can you see jquery being loaded?   If so, is it loaded at the top of the page (like in the head) or at the bottom?

Comment: Rockwell, I just liked at that and that's exactly what was happening. The jquery and all the scripts in stack.js where at the bottom of the layout, and while they were loading, they were loading after that one script. I just moved them to the header and that immediately resolved the issue. I have no idea how this worked at one point since the location for those hasn't changed...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Rockwell, the problem here had to do with the location of the scripts. Moving them to the header so they loaded before dependent scripts fixed the issue.